# Next.js app router, how to call timer after user refreshes page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, refresh-token

I'm using react and next.js (app router) and after logging in I call the below method called startRefreshTokenTimer() which will refresh my token one minute before it expires, which works great.

But in case of a page refresh the timer stops counting down so I will need to call startRefreshTokenTimer() again in order to verify the expiration date of the jwt token in my local storage. So how en where do I call startRefreshTokenTimer() if someone presses F5 somewhere on my website?

```
private refreshTokenTimeout: any;
async startRefreshTokenTimer() {
    const token = this.getToken();
    if (!token) return;

    const jwtToken = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
    const expires = new Date(jwtToken.exp * 1000);  

    const timeout = expires.getTime() - Date.now() - 60 * 1000;     

    this.refreshTokenTimeout = setTimeout(async () => {          
        await this.refreshToken();            
    }, timeout);
}

async refreshToken() {   
    const token = this.getToken();
    if (!token) return;
  
    const response = await axiosBearerToken.post(            
            `https://localhost:5001/api/auth/refresh-token`,
            {},
            { withCredentials: true }
        );

   this.setAuth(response.data.jwt); // puts token in local storage
   this.startRefreshTokenTimer();

   return true;        
}
```

Do I need to use :

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
```

and if so where do i put that code ? All my pages are rendered server side by default. Users can press F5 anywhere on my website.